# Why am I calculating two different Norton currents for a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Assume a circuit like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmAQUn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where R1 is an arbitrary impedance X, and R2 is an arbitrary impedance Y.

I can calculate I_norton by finding the short circuit current, which is V/X

Or, I can calculate the thevenin impedance of the circuit, which is 1/(1/x + 1/y) and then dividing V by the impedance of the circuit, I can get I_norton, which would be V*(1/x + 1/y). They aren't the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: R1 and R2 are NOT in parallel, but you have calculated the equivalent resistance using equation for a parallel circuit.  R1 and R2 are in series.

Comment: How are they in series? Once you remove the voltage sources, R1 and R2 are in parallel

Comment: You have one voltage source, and the two resistors are in series.  That is almost a text book example of a series circuit.

Comment: I see what you mean, but since R1 and R2 are at an equipotential at the top and bottom, aren't they also in parallel? So, can't you solve it that way?

Comment: @Goldname I understand why you think they are parallel, but they're not. They would have been, if, for example, there was another component to the right of R1, or in parallel to R2.

Comment: A component to the right of R1 would not make it parallel though, and a component in parallel to R2 wouldn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

You are right in that the Norton (or Thevenin) impedance is the parallel combination of the two resistors.  That is 50 Ω in this case.

The Thevenin voltage is V1/2.  That can be seen from inspection since R1 and R2 form a voltage divider with a gain of 1/2.

You are also right that the Norton current is V1 / R1, since that's the short-circuit output current.

You should be able to derive the same Norton current by dividing the Thevenin voltage by the Thevenin (or Norton) impedance.  This also works.  That is (½ V1)/(R1 // R2), which is also (½ V1)/(½ R1), which is V1/R1.

I didn't follow exactly what you did, but I think you might have forgotten that the Thevenin source voltage is 1/2 of V1.

Comment: Exactly so, Olin, OP's statement "Divide V by the impedance of the circuit" should be "Divide V_Thevenin by the impedance of the circuit"....where impedance is R1||R2.

Comment: I think there are several problems I am having. First, can't you do a parallel combination and a series combination to get the thevenin resistance? Why does that not yield the same thing?

Comment: Also, Vth /Rth is different than simply V / X because Vth = V*Y/(X+Y) and Rth = 1/(1/X+1/Y). Vth/Rth and V/x aren't the same thing.

Comment: no, i didn't forget that part

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following diagrams help. The BIG blue arrow is just treating \$R_X\$ and \$R_Y\$ as a voltage divider to work out the voltage at A relative to B and then replacing the resistance with the parallel equivalent of \$R_X\$ and \$R_Y\$ (which I assume you've learned to do, already.) I also just went step by step through the Nortonizing path, and then as a final step back to the Thevenin equivalent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxGgP8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can't you get the thevenin resistance without converting to a current source?

Comment: @Goldname I was just trying to help. I thought, from your question, that it might. But I probably wasn't able to read your mind and completely missed what you wanted. I'll be happy to delete it if it is no help to you.